# Select an object which returns checkbox checked/unchecked from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have been woking on this for quite some time now and it is driving me crazy. I have an image which when selected or clicked returns relevant information about from mysql db. One of these is a checkbox with checked or unchecked. The problem I am having is that I can echo input fields with the information but I cannot set the checkbox to checked or unchecked on click.

What I think is the problem line of code is below and the whole lot of it underneath if it helps to answer this question. Thanks.

Problem line: $('#element_lock').val($(this).attr('element_lock'), { id: id });

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click").click(function(){
    id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#id').val($(this).attr('id'), { id: id });
        $('#element_lock').val($(this).attr('element_lock'), { id: id });
    })
});
</script>

<div class="tooltip columns">
<div class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" id="element_lock" class="onoffswitch-checkbox matchedit field" change="postinput()"/>
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
<div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
<div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
</label>
</div>
</div>

<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM elements WHERE appear = 'Yes'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row['element_id'];
        $element_lock = $row['element_lock'];
        $image_name = $row['image_name'];
?>

<div id="display"></div>

<img
class="click"

id="<?php echo $id ?>"
element_lock="<?php echo $element_lock ?>"

src="../article_images/<?php echo $image_name ?>"

id="<?php echo $id ?>">

<?php } ?>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".matchedit").change(function() {
        var id = $("input#id").val();
        var element_lock = $("input#element_lock").val();
        $.post('change.php', {
        element_lock:element_lock,
        id:id
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element_lock').prop('checked', true);
```

Or set to false.